# postLogin() method redirection after login in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want my AuthController to check for few conditions and redirect to the respected routes accordingly. I want to check the if the logged in user's DB has particular columns are not empty. If its not empty i am redirecting to home page else I am redirecting to another route. I have used postLogin method. the issue here is its not checking the condition at all and directly redirecting to home even if the condtion fails. I tried to log in with new users whose details in DB are not filled , then also it redirected me to the home page and same happened with user who has his personal details filled in DB

here is the code of my AuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/user-prof';


    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {


        $email = $request->email;
        $user = \Auth::user();

        if(($user->username && $user->phone && $user->bio && $user->dobday && $user->dobmonth && $user->dobyear && $user->firstname 
            && $user->lastname && $user->topics && $user->nationality)!= NULL)
        {
            redirect('home');
        }

        else
        {
            redirect('/user-prof');
        }

        return $this->login($request);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I also want to know if i am checking the DB column data in the right way in IF condition inside the `postLogin()` method.

Comment: Create a function in your model that check those attibutes and call it in the condition.

Comment: you are not `return`ing those redirects, you are just creating a redirect response and doing nothing with it.   Though I really am not sure why your postLogin route is trying to retrieve the currently auth user, which there should not be one at this point.   I feel like this is stuff you should be checking in `authenticated` instead, which gets called after a successfull authentication via `handleUserWasAuthenticated`

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean to do those checks after the user has been 'authenticated' and logged in. You can define a `authenticated` method on your AuthController that will be called by `handleUserWasAuthenticated` after the user has been authenticated.

Something like this perhaps. (Get the user's attributes, only get the ones we want to check, use `array_filter` to remove the nulls, see if all the required fields are there).

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    $required = [
        'username', 'phone', 'bio', 'dobday', 'dobmonth', 'dobyear',
        'firstname', 'lastname', 'topics', 'nationality'
    ];

    $userAtts = array_filter(array_only($user->toArray(), $required));

    if (count($userAtts) != count($required)) {
        return redirect('/user-prof');
    }

    return redirect('home');
}
```

This doesn't change any methods the AuthController already has via the traits, it just adds a method that `handleUserWasAuthenticated` will check to see if exists, and if so will call it.

`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers@login -> @handleUserWasAuthenticated`

If you intend on 'caging' the user until these fields are filled in, then I would go with a middleware option similar to what @Ravi's answer is saying, but would have to be applied to a lot of routes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not override the method in Authcontroller. Use an after-middleware on postLogin route to check the conditions and route accordingly.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

There is one other way to do it;  however, I wouldn't suggest you do it. You may modify the RedirectsUsers trait. It is a Laravel file and will be defaulted back to original at every composer update. Although you can have a look at it to understand the redirection

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php

Comment: it is perfectly fine to override those methods. the control is in your application space and you can make it work how ever you wish

Comment: Of course it is. I was just a bit too impatient to read the entire code in the question, and answered whatever popped in my mind first. I do find your answer educational. +1